# Shared variables and suppressing details sections

Tags: crystal-reports

I have done loads of google searches and nearly have the answer to this but not quite.

From top to bottom of a report I have;

Report header a

Report header b

Page Header

Group Header

Details a

Detials b

------Sub Report1

------Sub Report2

Detials c etc

Group footer

etc

In Sub report 2 I have a shared variable 'stringvar dkrows2str;'

I want to suppress 'Details c' if this string is empty. I've been altering code but in the suppress section of Detials c i curent have;

shared stringvar dkrows2str;

stringvar array dkRow;

dkRow := split(dkrows2str,chr(13));

if (Count(dkRow)>0) then false else true;

So if the array has elements, dont suppress, else suppress.  Thouble is it always displays Detials c.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Determine the correct value of `dkrows2str` for the records you want to suppress. (Is it `""`?)
2. Confirm that you're getting the value you expect. Add a formula that contains just `dkrows2str`, place it in the detail section, and examine the values.
3. Rewrite your **Suppress** formula to use `dkrows2str` – it's the simpler of the two variables.

Ordinarily I'd suggest checking for null, but I don't think variables can have null values. So perhaps this:

```
dkrows2str = ""
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer noa.  How do I check variable values?  I cant see how to debug?

Comment: Ignore last comment - you've told me how to do this.  Thanks.